# database ressetting after running (debugging) program

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This is my first time asking a question here but I am completely puzzled by this. I'm currently making a small scheduling app as a side project but I keep running into this bug after I run my program. The bug is that I have made some changes to my database like adding a column Day_Night_Shift but after running the program it sometimes eliminates the row. Its like it reverts back to the old database. I am currently using an access database with accdb file.

so far I do a some inserts and select statements in the program. 
the first is the select statement which goes to this function to fill a dgv box.

```
Public Function executeQuery(ByVal querystr As String) As DataTable
'opens accdb database file and fills datatable with wanted query. returns datatable for use. 

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(querystr, connstr) 
        da.Fill(dt)
        da.Dispose()

    End Using

    Return dt
End Function
```

the other function I use is with inserting

```
 Public Function InsertNewEmp(ByVal firstname As String, ByVal lastname As String, ByVal position As String, ByVal shift As String) As String

 Dim insertstring As String = "INSERT INTO Tbl_Employee ([Employee First Name], [Employee Last Name], [Position ID], [Day or night]) VALUES ('" & _
  firstname & "', '" & lastname & "', " & position & ", '" & shift & "') "

 Try
        cnnOLEDB = New OleDbConnection(connstr)
        cnnOLEDB.Open()
        cmdOLEDB = New OleDbCommand(insertstring, cnnOLEDB)
        cmdOLEDB.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnnOLEDB.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "insert failed," & ex.Message
    End Try

Dim data As DataTable = executeQuery("SELECT [Employee ID] from Tbl_Employee where [Employee First Name] = '" & firstname & _
                                         "' and [Employee Last Name] = '" & lastname & "' and [Position ID] = " & position & _
                                         " and [Day or Night] = '" & shift & "'")

Dim successmsg As String
    Dim rows() As DataRow = data.Select()
    Dim lastrow As Integer = rows.GetUpperBound(0)
    successmsg = (rows(rows.GetUpperBound(0))(0))



    Return "insert successful Employee id=" & successmsg
```

If anyone is able to assist with this it would be much appreciated. Its not resetting the database all the time just some times but its a little annoying when i'm trying to debug etc.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have the database file listed between your project files and its property "Copy to the Output directory" is set to something different than "Never"?

Comment: can you elaborate more on that. I'm unsure what you mean? My file is in my bin/debug folder. i'm not sure what you mean by its property.

Comment: Thank you Steve, I was able to look around in VS and eventually found the "copy to the output directory" property I changed it and so far I haven't had the problem again. tyvm.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of: its not really an error.
What happens is when you start up your project visualBasic loads the database into a container. It saves and stores any data added, edited and/or deleted to this container. Once you close visual basic and opens it again its gone. I had this issue myself and as just as puzzled until i tried finishing and installing the program it all seemed to work perfectly fine.

It's no big deal at all, but i would advice keeping away from auto-generated stuff and use proper SQL, this way you don't have this issue and have better control over your database